# Subquery equation left part the same as right part, Why?

Tags: postgresql

```
  \set season 'date ''1978-01-01'''
select forename,surname, constructors.name as constructor, 
    count(*) as races, 
    count(distinct status) as reasons
from drivers join results using(driverid) 
    join races using(raceid) 
    join status using(statusid) 
    join constructors using(constructorid) 
where date >= :season and
 date < :season + interval '1 year'
and not exists   
     (select 1from results r where position is not null and r.driverid = drivers.driverid 
and r.resultid = results.resultid) group by constructors.name, driverid 
order by count(*) desc;
```

The inline subquery:

```
(select 1 from results r where position is not null and r.driverid = drivers.driverid and r.resultid = results.resultid)
```

, R refer to Table: results, so the last part become `results.resultid = results.resultid`
If the left and right part of equation is the same, why put it. So I don't got this part.

Answer (score 0):

Both `results` and `r` refer to selects from table `results`. However these are two separate selects, imagine doing this query. `select r1.resultid as r1, r2.resultid as r2 from results r1, results r2` . If you have n rows in table you recieve n*n rows in result.

Comment: I get it. But in this case, it is select 1, so I am still confused.

Comment: In this case "select 1" itself has no particular meaning; it is just to get the correct format to make a valid select statement. I myself typically use "select null" to accomplish the same.